# How can Firefox's per-site Flash permission be revoked again?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, flash-player

According to [How to block Flash again after mistakenly choosing "Allow and Remember"?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1072435), `If you ever need to revoke a permission for a site, you can use the Permissions panel of the Page Info dialog.`

However, it doesn't work in https://www.fjsoft.at/en/ in which the menu is in Flash (menu.swf). I've approved (in v62.0.2 64-bit) the browser's Flash warning to see how the menu looks like. Once done, I've wanted to revoke that permission and couldn't (I've even tried to choose Block in vain):
[image: Flash permission isn't used]

Comment: I can't replicate the problem (FFv62).  I went to that site and allowed Flash.  Then changed the setting back to default (always ask), and reloaded the page.  Flash was disabled and I had to allow it again.  Did you reload the page after changing the setting?

Comment: I did refresh, opened it in another tab, etc. Assuming you used Firefox, maybe you used a hard refresh and I didn't? I didn't mention it was in a Private Window, in case it matters. Weirder still, now it's blocked again for me, as if after a while it reverted to the default.

Comment: I'm not sure what effect a private window would have on this.  In my case, I just clicked the reload button (the circular arrow on the address bar).  If it's now properly blocked again, this will be hard for others to replicate.  It could be a conflict with an add-on, or something else specific to your setup.  See if you can replicate it in a regular window in case the private window limits some of the actions and controls.  If it isn't that, restart FF in safe mode (from the Help menu); it temporarily disables add-ons to see if one of them is causing indigestion.

Comment: I just tried it in a private window, and that didn't affect it.  It's possible that if you opened the site in a normal window, opened a copy in a private window, allowed Flash in the normal window, and reset it to default in the private window (or some similar action), that what you did in the private window might not affect the normal window.  But I'll assume that wasn't what was going on in your case.

Comment: No, I was in a private window from the start.